# How to insert line endings in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I was wondering how I could perform output in multiple lines in Sinatra. Eg.

```
get '/test' do
  array= ["one","two","three"]
  "#{array.each { |elem| elem}}"
end
```

ideally would have output:

```
one
two
three
```

not `onetwothree`

I'm fairly new to Sinatra and Ruby (first day of study) so please apology me for basic question (can't find answer anywhere)

Comment: I'd write that as: `array = %w[ one two three ]` :)

Comment: The problem is not in Sinatra, it's in your understanding of how HTML and browsers work. Unless a tag says otherwise, a browser will collapse whitespace resulting in text displaying on one line. The `<pre>` tag causes the browser to honor whitespace. See [HTML Basics--Whitespace](http://www-sul.stanford.edu/tools/tutorials/html2.0/whitespace.html) and [Paragraphs, Lines and Phrases](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Plain text newlines

```
["one", "two", "three"].join("\n")
```

or for HTML line breaks:

```
["one", "two", "three"].join("<br>")
```

Reference: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002182

Note: It's not a sinatra problem. Newlines are intepreted differently in HTML, plain newlines aren't interpreted as such by HTML, unless they are inside a `<pre>` block; outside `<pre>` `<br>` is used for linebreaks.

Comment: "\n" also works together with "response['Content-Type']= 'text/plain'"